# I need help understanding header files in C

Tags: c, header-files

I need some help understanding instructions for an assignment. I'm not asking for the code, I just need some guidance on where to start.

Comment: What exactly is your question about header files?

Comment: Do you know how to write the code for this without splitting it into a .h and a .c file?

Comment: Do you understand what it means if you have a single file that looks like: `int letterMatch(char *s, char c); int main(void) { ... }; int letterMatch(char *s, char c) { return 1;}`?  If so, just break that file into 3.  The line before `main` goes in the header file, and the function definition goes in `moreStrings.c`.  Then you just need to learn how to build an executable using multiple files.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that last bit

Answer (score 1):

Your `moreStrings.h` shall look like:

```
#ifndef MORESTRINGS_H
#define MORESTRINGS_H

int firstMatch(const char * str, const char c);

void letterMatch(const char * str, const char c);

#endif
```

Your `moreStrings.c` shall look like:

```
#include “moreStrings.h”

int firstMatch(char * str, char c)
{
    ... add code here
}

void letterMatch(char * str,char c)
{
    ... add code here
}
```

Then in `stringsMain.c` you can do stuff like:

```
#include "moreStrings.h"

int main(void)
{
    int index = firstMatch("Hello", 'l');
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm still a little confused on how to run the program once I've made the files though.

Comment: @Steff Depends on your compiler. It could be `gcc -Wall moreStrings.c stringsMain.c -o stringsMain`

Comment: Hi, I finished writing my code but I have some errors.

moreStrings.h:9:24: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘str’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 int firstMatch(const * str, const c);

moreStrings.h:9:24: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘str’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 int firstMatch(const * str, const c);

A lot of these are repeated, and I guess it has to do with the variable types I used. I was wondering if you could help me figure it out.

Comment: @Steff It doesn't sound as if you have done exactly what I wrote. Anyway - we need to see all your code so ask a new question about your current isuue and post all the code.

Comment: If a function is supposed to change an array in place, then it should probably not take `const char *str` as parameter. It would also be a good idea to let `moreStrings.c` include `moreStrings.h` to ensure there is no mismatch in the declarations.